# Linear maps preserving positive semidefiniteness

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

I know of Choi's theorem and some related problems, but not a solution to this exact problem:

> Characterize the linear maps from the space $S_n$ of symmetric $n \times n $ matrices to itself that preserve positive semidefiniteness.

It looks a natural question; has a simple characterization been found? Where can I find it?

Comment: What's Choi's theorem?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choi%27s_theorem_on_completely_positive_maps In short, it says that all completely positive linear maps (a stronger condition than preserving positive semidefiniteness) are precisely those in the form $\Phi(X)=\sum W_i X W_i^*$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat surprisingly, this seems to be still open. It is a linear preserver problem, about which there is a nice overview [here](http://people.wm.edu/~cklixx/lpp.pdf). But your specific problem seems to be open, according to this [recent preprint](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.3739.pdf). They also say that in an [earlier paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.1347v1.pdf) they settled the problem with some extra assumptions.